# nullpointerException handling onItemSelected

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have a problem with the `Spinner` implemented within my `Activity`. I believe I figured it out partially yet unclear how to go for a full solution. I have the following `Spinner` defining snippet:

```
 spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.regions, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

and the array populating this `Spinner` is in strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="regions">
    <item>West</item>
    <item>East</item>
    <item>Asia</item>
    <item>Africa</item>
    <item>Croatia</item>
</string-array>
```

Now the exception I get when I execute the application is `NullPointerException` in `onItemSelected` method implemented by `Spinner`. This is the method body:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView,View v,int position,long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Log.d("Position Value: ",(String.valueOf(position).toString()));
        if(position != 0)
        {
            if(spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() != null)
            { 
                filterObject.setRegion(spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            }else{
              filterObject.setRegion("Something Wrong!");
            }
        }
    }
```

If I removed the first check i.e. if position != 0, the app crashes immediately upon running. Once i placed that code here, the app loads ok and when I select an element in the `Spinner` it crashes immediately. What can solve this?

Thanks,

Error Log:

```
11-30 12:00:47.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19300): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 12:00:47.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19300): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 12:00:47.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19300):    at com.example.sketching.MainActivity.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:69)
11-30 12:00:47.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19300):    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:892)
11-30 12:00:47.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19300):    at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)
11-30 12:00:47.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19300):    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:860)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace from logcat.  It details exactly where the error occurs.  My guess is `filterObject`

Comment: It may be because before I implemented the filterobject things were working smoothly (at least the spinner). Check updated answer @Simon

Comment: where you are initializing filterObject?

Comment: OMG that was the mistake!!!! @GopalRao thanks mate. Write the answer and I am willing to mark it

Comment: Which is line 69? BTW, learn how to use the debugger.  These are simple bugs to work out with the debugger.  Trying to code without a debugger is like trying to build a car with only one spanner.  Not using the debugger is making things harder for you. Debuggers save an enormous amount of time and make everything easier.  The debugger will find gold in your garden and unicorns in the car park.  Writing Android Java code without using the debugger will cause your teeth to turn blue and your knees to change places with your elbows.  Debugging aids digestion and keeps your breath sweet. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of that condition, At the time of `onCreate()` itself your `Spinner` `onItemSelected` will trigger. So You need to `Initialize` the `filterObject` before `implement` the `OnItemSelectedListener` for your `Spinner`